# Create GitHub release using CloudBuild

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, github-release

I have everyting automated with CloudBuild and additionally I'd like to create a GitHub release using the CloudBuild. In short, I prepare binary files and then I want to create a GitHub release using those files.

I cannot find any working example. What should the appropriate step look like?
Additionally, I'm not sure about the authentication between GitHub <-> CloudBuild.

Comment: Maybe try adapting a script like [this one](https://gist.github.com/mcguffin/746afffa0929ca8e2ea2ba8538776742) and calling it from a new step with a bash entrypoint. For the authentication between GitHub and CloudBuild you need a Personal Access Token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can refer to the [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository) (click GitHub cli tab) where
  how to create a release using CLI is explained stepwise.
- There is also a separated [command Doc](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_upload) for how to add files to
  the release.
- To use Github Cli in cloud build , the best Practice would be to use
  community builder , for more information how to use it you can refer
  to the Documentation where  [Readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/github) contains a more detailed
  view.

For more information, you can visit to the  [Public Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-community-and-custom-builders) where it is mentioned as :

> This page explains how to [use community-contributed builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/github) and
> custom builders in Cloud Build. The Cloud Build developer community
> provides [open-source builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community)  that you can use to execute your
> tasks. If the task you want to perform requires capabilities that are
> not provided by an existing image, you can build your own custom image
> and use it in a build step. To learn about the different types of
> builders, see [Cloud Builders](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-builders).

Comment: @Matix123 Posted an answer, is it helpful?